# Prefer one row/ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query (simplified):

```
SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY name ASC
```

Now I want to prefer one ID - this one should be selected as first, and then the others should be selected (with a `ORDER BY`). You can imagine this like two queries that are merged together:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ID = 1
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ID != 1 ORDER BY name ASC
```

Or - if it is better to understand:

```
SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY `ID` = 1, name ASC -- Invalid syntax, of course
```

How this is possible with MySQL (in one query)?

Comment: That isn't invalid syntax.... It should work because `ID = 1` evaluates to `0` or `1` in MySQL. That should work, but you would also need `DESC` because you want the `ID = 1` first (its sort value is `1`).  If it didn't work for you, what error message did you get?  (So `ORDER BY  ID = 1 DESC, name ASC` should be exactly what you need)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thank you very much. I had two things tried (your comment and the answer), but failed with both because of a small thing :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the top of my head, here is what I can offer. You can opt for using a Union in this case:

Your query would become:

```
(SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ID = 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ID != 1 ORDER BY name ASC)
```

This is a single query if that is what you desire.

Comment: I already tried it with union - exactly as you written - but without brackets :-D I will try this, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, the solution of the commentator is better - because it is shorter :-)